# Pass the fetched data from an API and use it to style buttons using React and Sass

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have fetched some data from an API using which I created a list of buttons. Let's say the data I received looks like below -

```
  { name: "bob", colorCode: "#DC7472" },
  { name: "ben", colorCode: "#69DCD1" },
  { name: "john", colorCode: "#1570C5" },
  { name: "joe", colorCode: "#1550C4" }
];
```

Using this data, I created buttons and the name of the buttons corresponds to the name property in each of the array item.

Each of the button has the initial state of false, and onClick of the button, it toggles to true and false.

Now, when any of the button's state is true, I want to use the background-color as the respective colorCode property and the button text color to white.

Similarly, when it is false, I want the button text to be of the respective colorCode property and background color to white.

The initial state looks like below -

```
{
 bob:false,
 ben:false,
 john:false,
 joe:false
}
```

You can find the code here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dam8vt

I am struggling on how to achieve that using React and Sass?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] with the code you have so far.

Comment: @TJ You can find my code on stackblitz here [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dam8vt)

Comment: Are you using state component or function component with react ?

Comment: @JérômeW Using function component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
style={domain[each.domainName]? { color: each.colorCode, backgroundColor: "white" } : null}
```

Updated: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eocdma

Comment: Thank you @TJ . I was struggling with this a lot.

Comment: instead of `null` you can do this `style={domain[each.domainName]? { color: each.colorCode, backgroundColor: "white" } : { color: "white", backgroundColor: each.colorCode }}` so the text color and background toggles correctly

Comment: @TonyZhang Yes, I did that. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @MohitChauhan btw you can also do something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7h65np, directly using api response as initial state

Comment: @TJ now I am able to wrap my head around it. But what if I want to add more styles irrespective of the ternary operators. Like those are the common styles for both the conditions

Comment: @MohitChauhan add the common styles in a CSS class and do `classsName="common-styles-class"`. You can also switch classes with a ternary operator

Comment: @TJ thanks again for the help :)